# Problem about double space in list of figures when using endfloat package

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing, endfloat

I'm writing a manuscript using `endfloat` to make all the figures at the end of the article.

However, when using the code below to eliminate numbers from lists of figures, the definition `\AtBeginDelayedFloats{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}}` does not work:

```
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{%
\setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}%
\noindent\hspace*{1.5em}#1\hfil\newline }
```

By the way, `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}` works well if the above code does not exist.

Any suggestion?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lists]{endfloat}

\AtBeginDelayedFloats{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{%
\setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}%
\noindent\hspace*{1.5em}#1\hfil\newline }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{title}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{figure}[!ht]\caption{This is caption 1}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\caption{This is a long caption 2 This is a long caption 2 This is a long caption 2 This is a long caption 2}\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4):

There are three problems in your input.

1. Redefinitions of code that contains commands with an `@` in their names should be surrounded by special commands

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{%
     \setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}%
     \noindent\hspace*{1.5em}#1\hfil\newline }
   \makeatother
   ```

   Unfortunately the documentation of `endfloat` doesn't make this very clear.
2. The code for figures must be properly input with `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` on lines by themselves:

   ```
   \begin{figure}[!htp]
   <code for the figure>
   \caption{The caption}\label{label}
   \end{figure}
   ```

   (the `\label` is optional, of course).
3. Changing the definition of `\baselinestretch` is not sufficient, in general for getting increased line space: often the first paragraph will *not* be spaced. Use

   ```
   \AtBeginDelayedFloats{\linespread{1.4}}
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your correction. But the line-spacing is not change by the definition \AtBeginDelayedFloats{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}}

Comment: @toby Use `\AtBeginDelayedFloats{\linespread{1.4}}`.

Answer (score 2):

I found below command work well：

```
\AtBeginDelayedFloats{\linespread{2}\selectfont}
```